# Validate textarea before form submission

Tags: jquery

How can you validate a `<textarea>` after data has been entered (blur?) and before a form has been submitted?

For instance, I have a `<textarea>` and the user enters in this data:

```
alpha beta charlie delta
```

After the user is done entering in this data and the textarea is no longer focused, I'd like for it to validate and alert the user if they entered the word `beta`

Comment: `form onsubmit` trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `blur()` function if you want to trigger the validation if and only if the textarea has been unfocused - the `focusout()` function works better when you want to trigger validation regardless of which input field has been unfocused in the form.

An example would be:

```
$("textarea").blur(function() {
    var userInput = $(this).val();
    if(userInput.match(/beta/gi)) {
        // If there's a match, do this
    } else {
        // If there isn't a match, do this
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the `.focusout()` function:

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/